# How can my splash screen be implemented into Vue?

Tags: vue.js, gsap

Side note:

The splash screen code below from my Vue app is a view file not a component. Also I'm suing Vue router.

So below is my code, this is a splash screen using Gsap that has a callback function that I can later put in a route that goes to '/' which is the Home view.

How can I have this view showed first when launching the Vue app? And then once the animation is completed the callback will direct the user to the home page. Also one more thing, I'm not sure how this would work, but I want to make sure that once a user goes to the home page and some reason they refresh they don't have to see the splash screen again. How can that also be achieved?

Note: I did try to mess with the index.js under router but nothing worked and redirect never allowed the user to get to the home page.

HTML:

```html
<template>
  <div class="module_wrapper">
    <h1 ref="title">Welcome</h1>
    <div ref="module" class="module">
      <div class="top_wrapper">
        <div ref="box1" class="box box_1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom_wrapper">
        <div ref="box2" class="box box_2"></div>
        <div ref="box3" class="box box_4"></div>
        <div ref="box4" class="box box_5"></div>
        <div ref="box5" class="box box_3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```js
import { TimelineLite, Back } from 'gsap';

export default {
  methods: {
    onCompleteAll () {
      console.log('done');
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    const {module} = this.$refs;
    const {title} = this.$refs;
    const {box1} = this.$refs;
    const {box2} = this.$refs;
    const {box3} = this.$refs;
    const {box4} = this.$refs;
    const {box5} = this.$refs;
    const {top} = this.$refs;
    const {bottom} = this.$refs;
    const timeline = new TimelineLite({onComplete: this.onCompleteAll});

    timeline.to(module, 1.3, {scale: 1, ease: 'elastic.out(1, 0.5)',})
      .to(box1, 0.5, {opacity: 1, translateY: 0, ease: Back.easeInOut}, '-=0.4')
      .to(box2, 0.5, {opacity: 1, translateY: 0, ease: Back.easeInOut}, '-=0.4')
      .to(box3, 0.5, {opacity: 1, translateY: 0, ease: Back.easeInOut}, '-=0.4')
      .to(box4, 0.5, {opacity: 1, translateY: 0, ease: Back.easeInOut}, '-=0.4')
      .to(box5, 0.5, {opacity: 1, translateY: 0, ease: Back.easeInOut}, '-=0.4')
      .to(top, 0.4, {marginLeft: 10 + '%', ease: Back.easeInOut}, '-=0.2')
      .to(bottom, 0.4, {marginLeft: 10 + '%', ease: Back.easeInOut}, '-=0.2')
      .to(title, 0.4, {
        translateY: 0,
        opacity: 1,
        ease: Back.easeInOut
      }, '-=0.8');
  }
};
```

CSS:

```css
#app {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  outline: none;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html, body {
  transform: perspective(1px) scale(1) translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(#656565, #000000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.module_wrapper {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 13.4375rem;
  width: 18.75rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.4375rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.module {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  width: 18.75rem;
  height: 11.375rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.top_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
}

.bottom_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 50%;
}

.box {
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 0.4375rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.box_1 {
  width: 14.375rem;
  height: 3.6rem;
}

.box_2, .box_3, .box_4, .box_5 {
  width: 2.875rem;
  height: 3.25rem;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing some old and some new syntax for GSAP. We recommend all new syntax. It's [easy to upgrade](https://greensock.com/3-migration/)!

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m completely new to GSAP and this layout is what I found doing some research online. I’ll definitely convert to the new syntax! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a [Navigation Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to your `/` route.

The general idea is:
-Check if the user has already authenticated
-if they have, call `next()`
-if they haven't, redirect them to the login/splash page: `next('login')`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however I decided to change it to be strictly a component instead. I was able to get it working with local storage, however I’m still looking for better efficient ways that local storage wouldn’t need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options, but I think the best one will be to control the component's visibility in App.vue rather than inside the component. When the animation is over emit something to the parent, listen to that thing in the parent, and change the component visibility.

In order to display animation only one time, use session storage or local storage, and as the first job on page load, check if storage has anything about that. If it doesn't play your animation.

Comment: I like your idea so I followed through and I was able to get it working with local storage. I also change it to be a component instead. However, I did do some more research online and saw that some people recommend placing a splash screen of animation into the public/index.html file itself between the #app element. Then just make the app render after some delayed time and the splash screen gets erased. I haven’t yet tried this out, but what do you think about it? I’m asking because I’m very new to Vue and GSAP all together.

Comment: Moving animation to index sounds logical. But you have to sure that your animation takes long enough, so the app can be loaded while it's playing. No need to delay the app, just let it wait for the completion of the animation.